# Resolving a domain name to an IP address in C

Tags: c

I have been trying to figure out how to do this for a day or two now. I have tried to copy code online too and I keep getting a segmentation fault for some reason and I don't have clue why.

Here is my code I currently have. (Copied from a YouTube video in which the code ran flawlessly.)

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct hostent *host_info;
    struct in_addr *address;

    char input[20];

    strcpy(input, "stackoverflow.com");
    printf("Will do a DNS query on: %s\n", input);

    host_info = gethostbyname(input);
    address = (struct in_addr *) (host_info->h_addr);
    printf("%s has address %s\n", input, inet_ntoa(*address));
}
```

Comment: Works for me, for what it's worth. Can you run this in a debugger to see which line you're getting the segfault on? Any chance gethostbyname is failing and returning null?

Comment: Make sure you check the returned values of `gethostbyname` to make sure it isn't NULL.

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){`  Since the two parameters are not used, the compiler outputs to warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`  `int main( void )`

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include <netinet/in.h>` and `#include <sys/socket.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` Nothing in the posted code is using any of the contents of those header files.  It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used

Comment: when calling C library functions, always check the returned value for any error indication.  Is there some entry in the `hosts` file that is causing the problem?

Comment: What platform? IDE (may imply what compiler)? Compiler ([GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM), [Microsoft Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B), etc.), bitness (32 or 64 bit), and operating system/type. All including versions. Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62623611/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:" or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: See [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) for an example that does just that, updated to use the latest approaches conducive to both IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess most of the *gethostbyname* function fails to execute. You can check whether its return value is null. In addition, you can try the *inet_ntop* function instead of the *inet_ntoa* function.

Comment: I ran the OPs code, as posted, and this is the result:  *Will do a dns query on: stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.193.69*  So there is some (outside of this code) problem

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me. Redoing this for other inet libraries shouldn't be too hard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>


using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int RSV2IP4(const char* hostname, char* ip4str, size_t ip4str_len) {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize Winsock\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo* result, * rp;
    int status;

    // Set up the hints structure to specify the desired options (IPv4, TCP).
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP socket

    // Use getaddrinfo to resolve the address.
    status = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &result);
    if (status != 0) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        WSACleanup();
        return 2;
    }

    // Iterate through the results to find the IPv4 address.
    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        struct sockaddr_in* ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in*)rp->ai_addr;
        void* addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);

        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, addr, ip4str, ip4str_len) != NULL) {
            // Successfully resolved the IPv4 address.
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Failed to resolve an IPv4 address.
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 3;
}
```

Comment: OP is using `arpa/inet.h`, and is likely on linux. This answer depends on windows (`winsock2.h`). Note he question itself is a little old, the original OP has likely moved on.

Comment: Not to mention the question is tagged `C` and this is a `C++` answer. (though admittedly, it is better than the accepted answer...)